# Do I commit ProjectA or ProjectA/src to SVN?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, version-control, commit

In `Java`, I've been recommended not to commit the `bin` folder (with `.class` files), the `lib` folder (for external Jar files) or the `.project` or `.classpath` files.

This would leave `src` (source code) and `test` (unit tests).

Given this, is it best practice to instantiate on the SVN repository separately `ProjectA/src` and `ProjectB/test`, thus creating two `.svn` folders in these two folders? Or would I still only ever instantiate the entire `ProjectA` first off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tests are an integral part of the ProjectA project, and you definitely want them in the same repository as the sources that they test.

And you probably have (or will have) other directories in your project (documentation, build file, scripts, etc.). So put the project root directory under SVN, and make sure to ignore the `bin` directory.

Comment: This is maybe the 10th time you have helped me!

Comment: If you changed your name to something easier to remember, maybe I would remember you :)